# ListView's Item Layout error

Tags: android, listview

I am using following layout for my list view items.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://scheme.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:minHeight="40sp"
    />
```

But I am getting an error in the logcat java.lang.RuntimeException ... that you must supply a layout_width argument.

My main.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget28"
    android:background="#ff000033"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70px"
        android:layout_height="30px"
        android:paddingLeft="2px"
        android:paddingTop="2px"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     ></ImageView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/myListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my activity's onCreate code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    context=this.getApplicationContext();
    this.setTitle("NP Headline News");

    myListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

            @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int index,long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String urlAddress=urlAddresses[index];
                String urlCaption = urlsCaptions[index];
            }

    });

  int layoutId=R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
   // int layoutId=android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1;
    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,layoutId,this.urlsCaptions);

    myListView.setAdapter(aa);
}
```

I think that it is something related to my simple_list_item_1 because if I use android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 then every thing works ok

Comment: can you post the complete error text

Comment: Are you sure that RuntimeException refers to this layout? It seems correct... please paste the listview layout too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your error cleared layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:minHeight="40sp"

    />
```

Can you able to differentiate your error contained code and this above one.

I wish you guys to don't tense and urge while code something, that must be lead you to blocked and confused minded.

For these type of errors, you could use to debug yourself with the help of DDMS. 
Because the code is very very simple to view right.

And some words about the previous answers:

Guys that is not necessary to declare a `TextView` or any `View` only inside of the `Layout` file.

It is also a `View`, So it can capable to sit alone in a `Canvas`.

And also the problem is not by the `"fill_parent"`, and `"match_parent"` Something.

I think you might be tensed now also, because i am taking this much time to give you the reason of your error.

Here we go,

the error is because simply in the following line,

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

In the above line you mistakenly typed `scheme` instead of `schemas`.

That is the error.

So only i mentioned if you had look at the code with out tense you can get it easily.

`xmlns` denotes the namespace , that should be proper in order make the `android:`  prefixed attributes as valuable.

Hope you understand and the answer helpful to you.

Comment: @Raza No probs dude. chill... Do well

Comment: "added 910 characters in body" - really? Can't you find better description? Talking about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/241913) and using this method of contact as we don't have private message system. Anyway - when suggesting edits please do it properly.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for your suggestions. i cant see the description which i accepted the default one in my window. thts the reason i missed it. And hereafter i wont describe it like this, and my further suggestion wont be a minor one. i will make it proper. Thanks for intimating me.

Comment: No intimidation intended just trying to help you pass your edits better.

Answer (score 0):

YOU should puy your TextView under a Layout, since your are using a unique TextView  you could add a LinearLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView xmlns:android="http://scheme.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:minHeight="40sp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think it is possible to add a single Textview. Whether is makes sense is an other question, especially some attributes may be useless

Comment: @Pedro Teran : It is not a compulsory to put the `TextView` inside of the `Layout`. we can use it like he used.

Answer (score 0):

I guess problem comes from something different.

You are doing a custom item view, but you use standard AdapterView.

For a standard arrayAdapter you need to fulfil the expected structure.

Alternatively you build an own ArrayAdapter and supply your dedicated getView

[Android Custom Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038986/android-custom-listview)